# Assigning CRS using las2las from libLAS?

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, liblas

My las file had a spatial reference of "None." I tried to assign the CRS (in which data were collected) with the following command line:

```
las2las flightline_002.las --a_srs EPSG:32632
lasinfo --no-check flightline_002.las
```

Lasinfo still reports it as "None." See screenshot below, line 'Spatial Reference':

[image]

Those extent coordinates are UTM meters.

I am working through the examples on http://www.liblas.org/start.html#osx, with libLAS 1.7.0, GeoTIFF 1.4.0 GDAL 1.11.1, Mac OS 10.9.4. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the original (source) spatial reference?

Comment: None.  I mean, the data was collected in EPSG 32632, but that doesn't seem to be stored with the .las.

Comment: Those extent coordinates are UTM meters.

Comment: :)  I dunno -- let's see if I can clip it without a crs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`las2las flightline_002.las --a_srs EPSG:32632` doesn't modify `flightline_002.las`. Rather, it creates a new file called `output.las` with the spatial reference information. `output.las` is the default value of the `-o [ --output ]` option available in `las2las`.

To specify the new filename, use the following construction:

```
las2las --a_srs EPSG:32632 flightline_002.las flightline_002_w_srs.las
```