# How to assign/project las-file using R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, las, lidr

I have got a LAS file from a MLS, which has following specifications:

```
test <- lidR::readLAS("<file.las>")
print(test)
#> class        : LAS (v1.0 format 1)
#> memory       : 11.4 Gb 
#> extent       : -135.0345, 139.0671, -120.6662, 140.9799 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : NA 
#> area         : 55785.25 units²
#> points       : 152.99 million points
#> density      : 2742.47 points/units²
```

As you see, the  LAS file does not come with any CRS. However, I have the coordinates for a specific point in the point cloud in both, the internal x/y/z dimensions as well as in the CRS I want to assign/project my dataset into.

Furthermore I know the units of the internal x/y/z dimensions as well as that the point cloud has got a northing.

How to assing/project the LAS file into a specific CRS, when the LAS file does not have a specific CRS yet? In my case EPSG:32632 see URL:https://epsg.io/32632 )

see also:

- [How to assign (or project) CRS to LiDAR file in lidR?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281125/how-to-assign-or-project-crs-to-lidar-file-in-lidr)
- [Assigning CRS using las2las from libLAS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194254/assigning-crs-using-las2las-from-liblas)

Comment: Your question is not how to assign a CRS to a LAS files. But how to recompute the coordinates in a given CRS considering that the original data do no have a CRS and their coordinates are relative to the sensor. Which is unsolvable without something else to make the link. Do you have e.g. the long/lat of the (0,0) of your point cloud

Comment: yes, for a specific point (not the 0/0/0) in the las-file I have got the x/y/z-coordinates of the internal reference system as well as the x/y-coordinates in the required EPSG:32632. Furthermore I know about the unit of the internal reference system and that the point cloud has got a northing. So theoretically it should be possible to compute the coordinates of the point cloud in EPSG:32632 Or do I commit a fallacy?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ill-defined or at least not clear enough. To answer I'll assume that you know the long/lat of the (0,0) in your point-cloud. Without this assumption the problem is not solvable. Also I'll assume that your point cloud is already projected with meters units.

First I'm generating a reproducible dataset

```r
library(lidR)

X = runif(10000, -140, 180)
Y = runif(10000, -140, 180)
Z = runif(10000, 0, 20)
data = data.frame(X,Y,Z)
las = LAS(data)
```

Then I'm defining where on earth is (0,0) of the point cloud. Here I'm starting from long/lat but maybe you already have coordinates in your target CRS.

```r
library(sf)

target = st_crs(32617)
zero = c(-79.6, 48.4)
zero = st_point(zero)
zero = st_sfc(zero, crs = 4326)
zero = st_transform(zero, target)
```

Now I'm extracting the `X0` and `Y0` that will be used to translate your coordinates

```r
X0 <- st_coordinates(zero)[,1]
Y0 <- st_coordinates(zero)[,2]
```

And I'm applying the translation + assigning a CRS

```r
las@header@PHB[["X offset"]] <- floor(X0)
las@header@PHB[["Y offset"]] <- floor(Y0)
las$X = las$X + X0
las$Y = las$Y + Y0
projection(las) <- target
las
#> class        : LAS (v1.2 format 0)
#> memory       : 248 Kb 
#> extent       : 603482.7, 603802.6, 5361567, 5361887 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref.  : WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N 
#> area         : 102076.2 metre²
#> points       : 10 thousand points
#> density      : 0.1 points/metre²
```

---

For future reader: it is likely that future versions of `lidR` include a function `translate_points()` or similar name. Something like.

```r
las <- translate_points(las, X0, Y0)
```

Comment: following I don't get: You assume that the internal reference system of the scanner system is in epsg:4326, see ```zero = st_sfc(zero, crs = 4326)``` However, the .laz-file doesn't have any 'real' crs. It has an internal reference system (in units metre and a northing) set up for every single scan, where 0/0/0 is the origin (the position in the surrounding where the scan is started). All movements of the scanner system are tracked with an IMU and written with the point cloud. I know the exact coordinates in epsg:32632 for this 0/0/0 which should allow a transformation of the point cloud.

Comment: good, it you know where is 0/0/0 in epsg:32632 you only follow the subsequent steps